# session in symfony works in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: php, symfony, session, twig

Hello I have a problem with my code.

I have coded the game black jack in php, symfony and twig.

When I publish it to our student server it works fine on Chrome but not on firefox.

On my teachers computer it works on firefox but not in chrome.

Its alot of code to write here but basically

I use SessionInterface with symfony then

```
public function blackJackProcess(Request $request, SessionInterface $session) : Response {
        $play = $request->request->get('play');

        $blackJack = $session->get("blackjack") ?? new \App\Cards\BlackJack();

    
        if($play) {
            $blackJack->firstPlay();
            $session->set('blackjack', $blackJack);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('blackjack-start');
     }
```

And then in the route I redirect to I use the session blackjack like this:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/game/blackjack/start", name="blackjack-start", methods={"GET", "HEAD"})
     */
     public function blackJackStart(SessionInterface $session) : Response {
        //$hit = $request->request->get('hit');
        //$stay  = $request->request->get('stay');

        $blackJack = $session->get('blackjack') ?? new \App\Cards\BlackJack();

        //$firstdraw = $session->get('firstgame');

        $data = [
            'dealer' => $blackJack ->getDealerCards(),
            'player' => $blackJack ->getPlayerCards(),
            'dealerscore' => $blackJack ->getDealerScore(),
            'playerscore' => $blackJack->getPlayerScore(),
            'firstdraw' => $blackJack ->checkFirstDraw()
            




        ];

        return $this->render('game/blackjackstart.html.twig', $data);
     }
```

Can anyone see where I do things wrong and why its working in some browsers like chrome and safari but not firefox.
Or can it be our studentserver that is the problem.

It works fine locally on my localhost:8888/

Comment: You should start by checking that the browsers receive the session ID cookie correctly, and also send it back on the next request.

Comment: Define doesn't work? Do you get any errors? You are storing a full instance of an object in the session. Have you tried storing primitives in the session and restore the blackjack game rather than trying to store a (serialized) instance?